# MultiValueDictKeyError when trying to get POST charfield value using django

Tags: python, django

i have a django code which post value and retrieve it inside views.py . but when i tried to retrieve the data it is throwing me MultiValueDictkeyError . I checked whether any multiple values are passed but no where multiple values are passed . Can anyone check on this .

Here is my html file .

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >{% csrf_token %}
                     <p>  <label for="pa">App:</label>
    
                        <select name = "app">
                        <option value = "select" selected > Select   </option>
                        {% for i in result %}
                            <option value = "{{i.apptype}}" > {{i.apptype }}   </option>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                          &ensp; &ensp; &ensp; &ensp; &ensp; &ensp; &ensp; &ensp;&ensp; &ensp; &ensp; &ensp; &ensp; &ensp; &ensp; &ensp;
    
                        <label for="cu">Customer:</label>
    
                        <select name = "customerdrop">
                        <option value = "select" selected > Select   </option>
                        {% for j in result1 %}
                          <option value = "{{j.customer}}" > {{j.customer }}   </option>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </select>
    <button type="submit"style="background-color:#FFFF66;color:black;width:150px; height:40px;">Save Template</button>
                  <input type="button" style="background-color:#FFFF66;color:black;width:150px; height:25px;" value="Save Template as :"/>
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value=""/><br>
             </form>
```

Model.py

```
class config(models.Model):
    app = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    customerdrop = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
def pg2(request):
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                          'Server=abc\abc;'
                          'Database=UI;'
                          'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('inside Post')
        print(request.POST['app'])
        print(request.POST['customerdrop'])
```

so,
it prints " inside Post " , and app too , but not customerdrop . Can anyone help me on this thing .

Comment: `MultiValueDictkeyError` just means that the key is not present. Access the keys using the `get` method like this `request.POST.get('app')`.

Comment: tried that , but it is returning me a NONE @VishalSingh , May i know the reason for that . Am new to django , so i really don't know what i missed .

Comment: get yourself acquainted with [dictionary](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary) and [QueryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict)

Comment: but how to use this with the code i have @VishalSingh , Please explain

Answer (score 0):

you need to handle the condition

try this

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    app = request.POST.get('app')


or 


if request.method == 'POST':
    
    try:

        app = request.POST['app']

    except:

        app = None
```

Comment: it returns "None"

Comment: when i use first method